# QGIS upper round in field calculator

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

With the field calculator, I need to do the following calc: toint(Field1 / 25.0) but i need to round the result to no decimal places but upwards. Examples:

- If 17/25 result should 1.
- If 25/25 result should 1.
- If 26/25 result should 2.
- If 51/25 result should 3.
  ...

I guess I need to use round function but it is not giving the results I am expecting.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are using the wrong rounding function:

- `ceil`: rounds up (to the ceiling)
- `round`: rounds to the nearest value
- `floor`: rounds down (to the floor)

If you select a function, you can see the help documentation in the pane on the right hand side of the field calculator window.  This will explain how to use each function.

Answer (score 3):

The function you're looking for is the 'ceiling' function, or `ceil` in the QGIS field calculator:

```
ceil(x/y)
```